# Why the variable b is not hoisted in this example?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am reading Javascript Definitive guide and i came across a statement about function scope:"*JavaScript’s function scope means that all variables declared within a function are visible **throughout the body of the function***"
Since bar() has a variable b in it which is in turn declared within function foo().Why b is not hoisted in this case and output is not undefined(Inner variable b should be visible throughout the body of foo() )?

```
var b =5 ; 
    function foo(x)
    {
      console.log(b);
      function bar()
      {
       var b=4;
      }

    }
    foo(4);
```

Comment: You answer your own question. Since bar is a function, b is scoped to bar. and is invisible to foo. Only bar is visible to foo, but everything inside bar isn't.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `b` within `bar` **is the `bar` function.** Variables are not visible *outside* their function. That would mean that *all* variables would be visible globally, since they would all propagate up into the global scope/outermost function. That's precisely what scope is supposed to prevent.

`b` is hoisted *within its scoping function*, which is `bar`; not `foo`.